# Insert into table only if there are no duplicates for the last 4 hours

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have two tables. BUYWALLDATA3 gets Truncated every time the program runs.

BUYWALL is where I want to store the data inserted into BUYWALLDATA3 for 4 hours.

Sometimes there are multiple entries for the same COINPAIR when running the code. But once those entries have been inserted I do not want to update the rows for that COINPAIR for 4 hours. Once those 4 hours are up I want to update those entries again.

This is because I have another script that analyses the data from BUYWALL in those 4 hours.

Any ideas how to do this?

This is for a crypto alert bot.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO BUYWALLDATA3 (COINPAIR, BUYWALLPRICE, BUYWALLSIZEINBTC, volumethreshold, datetimeofinsert) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
val = [
(whichmarket[f], var_element_check[0], sum_array_check, volume_threshold)
]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

cnx.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")


sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO BUYWALL (COINPAIR, BUYWALLPRICE, BUYWALLSIZEINBTC, volumethreshold, datetimeofinsert) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW()) "
val = [
(whichmarket[f], var_element_check[0], sum_array_check, volume_threshold)
]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

cnx.commit()
```

Here is the layout of both tables (they are both identical)

[image: The layout of both tables]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you keep creating new tables you're kind of missing the point of a relational database. Is there any way you could represent this with one table and additional columns/indexes to properly partition it?

Comment: what are some sources of table inserts, will ALL the table inserts be made from this Python script, or is there an app that makes the inserts in parallel.

Comment: I could put it all on one database and then only SELECT the rows which have been inserted less than 10 minutes ago (since this script is constantly running every 10 minutes). Currently my SELECT code is `sql = """SELECT * FROM BUYWALLDATA3 WHERE COINPAIR = '%s' """ % (key)` is there a way to make that only select the data where datetimeofinsert is no greater than 10 mins ago?

Answer (score 0):

You want to periodically backup the content of one of your table to another one, that has the same structure. It would be best to always save to the same, unique table.

Your source table has a timestamp field that can be used to filter records. You seem to be looking for a WHERE clause that filters data based on an interval of time ; that would be :

```
WHERE datetimeofinsert > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
```